# Invalid conversion from "const char *" to "char *" in strcat()

Tags: c++, c-strings

The following sample of code

```cpp
...
#include <cstring>
#include <set>

constexpr int BUFFER_MAX_SIZE = 1024;

struct connection
{
    ...
    char inputBuffer[BUFFER_MAX_SIZE];
    char outputBuffer[BUFFER_MAX_SIZE];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    std::set<connection> clientConnections;
    ...

    for (auto &clientConnection : clientConnections)
    {
        char buffer[BUFFER_MAX_SIZE];

        ...
        strncat(clientConnection.inputBuffer, buffer, BUFFER_MAX_SIZE);
        ...
        strncat(clientConnection.outputBuffer, buffer, BUFFER_MAX_SIZE);
        ...
    }
}
```

causes the error that is in the title for both strncat() calls. I have no idea why does it happen because as you can see inputBuffer and outputBuffer members are NOT declared as constant. Besides before I have made some changes in the code it worked fine. Can something else affect on this?

I suppose those lines are enough but I could add more ones later if required.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `string`?

Comment: @ghostinecatnewyear Provide a minimal program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: When I compile (an edited version of) your code I don't get the error. But your code has a number of 'issues' that will cause failure.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @ghostinecatnewyear And what is it trncat(clientConnection.clientConnection.inputBuffer, buffer, BUFFER_MAX_SIZE, buffer, BUFFER_MAX_SIZE);?

Comment: _"Besides before I have made some changes in the code it worked fine"_ Then look at your version control tool's history to find out what change broke it.

Comment: Iterating over set will always give you const-qualified items.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the order of the source and destination buffers reversed in your call to `strncat()`

```
char * strncat ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
```